# Are objects like $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$ consistent with Einstein summation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

I'm familiar with Einstein' summation notation and I understand objects like $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu}$ just fine.

But I'm wondering why I've never come across objects like this: $a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$. Is there a notation reason for this or do these objects just not come up? From what I can see,

$$a^{\mu \nu} a_{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu} = a^{0 0} a_{00} b^{0 0} + a^{1 0} a_{1 0} b^{1 0} +...$$
And so on for all permutations and indices. Is this a valid way of using Einstein's summation convention? Can one basically treat $a^{\mu \nu} b^{\mu \nu}$ as an object $c^{\mu \nu}$ with upper indices?

Comment: No. It is not. Indices can be repeated only twice -- no more. The type of object you are talking about never comes up in relativity.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case so I understand what part of the notation doesn't allow for this? For a simpler example, if $k=0,1$ and I want to look at an object like $a^k a_k b^k$ why is this not $a^0a_0b^0+a^1a_1b^1$?

Comment: well, of course, this is a notation and you could define it to be whatever you want. However, since this kind of sums never appear in tensor analysis (mostly because we use square norms), it is not a useful one in this context.

Comment: Yeah but I'm not trying to invent new notation, I'm trying to figure out if this is what Einstein sum convention would yield or not.^^

Comment: as I said earlier, no. The Einstein summation convention does not allow for more than two repeated indices. Only objects like $a^\mu b_\mu$ or $T_{\mu\nu} h^{\mu\nu}$ are allowed. $a^\mu b_\mu c^\mu$ is not well-defined within the summation convention.

Comment: BTW, the reason you almost never come across such objects is because the norms used in GR and relativity are square norms. The inner product is a map $V \times V \to {\mathbb R}$. If we were working with vector spaces with cubed norms where the inner product is a map $V \times V \times V \to {\mathbb R}$ then maybe we would have use for such a notation.

Comment: So then if I'm given a $a^\mu b_\mu$ and want each term of that sum to be multiplied with a different constant indexed by some $c^\alpha$ how would I make that work out while adhering to the convention? Note I want $c^1$ multiplied with $a^1 b_1$ and $c^2$ multiplied with $a^2 b_2$ and so on.

Comment: You could define a diagonal metric $g_{\alpha\beta}$ whose diagonal components are $g_{\alpha\alpha} = c_\alpha$ (no sum here). Then, the quantity you want to calculate is $g_{\alpha\beta} a^\alpha b^\beta$.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would scale to higher dimensions. So what if I wanted $a^{\mu \nu} b_{\mu \nu}$ to be multiplied with a list of constants $c^{\alpha \beta}$ but in each term I want the corresponding values? I'm not able to see a rule for this, yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35551/discussion-between-prahar-and-kurow).